# Least-Squares Derivation Looks Different

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, least-squares

Why does my least squares solution look different ? Here, $y$ and $w$ are vectors, while $X$ is a matrix.

$ \frac{1}{2}(y - Xw)^T(y-Xw) = y^Ty - y^TXw - w^TX^Ty + w^TX^TXw $

$ \frac{d}{dw} = -y^TX + X^TXw = 0$

$w = (X^TX)^{-1}y^TX$

but the solutions I see are

$w = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{d}{dw}(a^Tw)=\frac{d}{dw}(w^T a)=a\neq a^T.$$
Consequently,
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dw}(y^Ty - y^TXw - w^TX^Ty + w^TX^TXw)=\frac{1}{2}(-X^T y-X^T y+2 X^T X w)=0\implies?$$

Comment: ah okay. so are you saying that if i have specified y and w to be column vectors then my derivative wrt w must be in column vector format ?

Comment: @kong The derivative of a scalar w.r.t a (column) vector is also a (column) vector.